# Keras Sequential Classifier - Accuracy is low and not improving?

Tags: keras, neural-network, classification

I'm just getting started with neural networks and I've been running into a problem trying to build a classifier for some sounds (10 different classes).

I've got an X array with all the relevant features I have and an y with the associated class.
I tried to transform y so that it looks like this [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] for instance, where 1 is at it's class' index. I also tried normalizing X so that all the features are between 0 and 1 and now it looks like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWuF1.png)

The model I came up with looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXrm.png)

Here are my incredibly bad results :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqJgR.png)

The accuracy is terrible and even worse it's not improving... What am I doing wrong ? :0

I've tried changing the batch size, the number of epochs, to normalize my data a different, to give up the idea of normalizing them... always the same result !

Comment: Do you get any better training set accuracy without the dropout layers?

Comment: No it doesn't change anything :0